# What can I do to receive realtime data from website to my Android device

Tags: android, firebase, web, web-applications

I want to find way that can help me receive realtime data such as new enquiries, subscribers, new registrations data to my Android device in the form of web notification and store the data on my device in the table. How can I do it

I looking for comparatively easy way to do it.Without using any paid third party softwares.